# Limit visibility of related Contacts in an Experience site to only some related Account users

Tags: community, lightning-experience, account, sharing, contact

I would like to limit visibility of some of the contacts related to any given account to only some of the users related to that account.

So if Account A has 2 related experience users, Sally and Jim (who have a contact), and 20 related contacts. Sally can see all 22 contacts related to Account A but Jim can only see 4 of them.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/data_security/data_security_records is a good place to start.

Comment: Also take a look at [implicit sharing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_object_relationships_implicit_sharing.htm#!)